# sorting JSON array on users selected criteria

Tags: php

I have json array as follows:

```
{   

    "class": [
     {
        "name":"A",
        "std":"5"   
     },
       {
        "name":"B",
        "std":"4"   
     },  {
        "name":"C",
        "std":"6"   
     },  {
        "name":"D",
        "std":"9"   
     },{
        "name":"Z",
        "std":"3"   
     },  {
        "name":"H",
        "std":"0"   
     }, {
        "name":"I",
        "std":"1"   
     }

]

}
```

I have decoded the array and displayed it in table format by following code:

```
$file=getcwd()."/test1.json";
echo $file;
if (file_exists($file)) {

$t=file_get_contents(($file));
$t=json_decode($t);
echo "<pre>";
echo "<table>";
$default=$t->class;


    if(isset($t->class) && !empty($t->class)):
        foreach($t->class as $value):
            arsort($value);
            $vaule=(object) $value; 
            echo "<tr><td>$value->name</td><td>$value->std</td></tr>";           
        endforeach;
    endif;  

echo "</table>";
echo "The file exists";
} 

else {
echo "The file does not exist";
}
```

Now it want to sort the array according to the user selection from the drop down box,which looks like:

```
<form action="jason.php"  method="POST">
<select name="sort">
    <option value="asc">ASCENDING</option>
    <option value="desc">DESCENDING</option>
</select>

<select name="sortby">
    <option value="name">NAME</option>
    <option value="std">STANDARD</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/> 
</form>
```

I have tried using `usort()` but i cant get the answer
Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to use `usort();` because your `json_decode();` will return an object instead of an array.

To fix this you could use the second, optional `boolean` which will indicate the returntype.
By default this is false, if set to true, json decode will return an array, which you can then use `usort();` on.

e.g.

```
$t = json_decode($t, true); // returns array
```

However do note that objects are upto 50% (i believe) faster than arrays when filled.
For a small application this is not noticable but if your application attracts thousands of visitors I would see if there is a `usort();` for objects.